# How to get the selected filename from file_selector?

Tags: taipy

I want to display the selected filename when using file_selector for uploading a file.
Through state.path I get the full path where the filename has a number between name and suffix like this .../accounts-config.5.yaml.
Possible to filter the string to the original filename but is this the way to go?
I see a notification with the original filename when the button is pushed, indicate the filename should be available somewhere.

Either a yes, this is the way to go or an hint to a variable that could be used instead.

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the filename, you should filter on the path, like you said.